# Obtaining BinaryClassification FastTree FeatureNames for PFI Analysis

Tags: c#, ml.net

I've built a simple BinaryClassification FastTree model in ML.net 1.0.0 using a subset of columns in my trainingDataView. Now, I want to perform a PFI analysis but can't seem to isolate only the columns/features used in the model vs all columns in the IDataView.

I've been referencing the example at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.permutationfeatureimportanceextensions.permutationfeatureimportance?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_PermutationFeatureImportanceExtensions_PermutationFeatureImportance__1_Microsoft_ML_BinaryClassificationCatalog_Microsoft_ML_ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer___0__Microsoft_ML_IDataView_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Nullable_System_Int32__System_Int32_) PFI for Binary Classification.

```cs
var trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<FPPCNTKData>(TrainDataPath, hasHeader: false, separatorChar: ' ');

Var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features",
                                                "mCalc_FPP_Legs_Range",
                                                "mCalc_FPP_Legs_Ticks",
                                                "mCalc_FPP_Legs_Bars",
                                                "mCalc_FPP_Legs_TMins",
                                                "mCalc_FPP_Diag_RangeBars",
                                                "mCalc_FPP_Diag_RangeTMins",
                                                "mCalc_FPP_Diag_TicksBars",
                                                "mCalc_FPP_Diag_TicksTMins",
                                                "mCalc_XD_XA_Mult_Ticks",
                                                "mCalc_AB_XA_Mult_Ticks",
                                                "mCalc_AD_XA_Mult_Ticks",
                                                "mCalc_BC_XA_Mult_Ticks",
                                                "mCalc_BC_AB_Mult_Ticks",
                                                "mCalc_CD_AB_Mult_Ticks",
                                                "mCalc_CD_BC_Mult_Ticks",
                                                "mCalc_CD_BD_Mult_Ticks")
     .Append(mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FastTree(labelColumnName: "mHiProfitOneHot", featureColumnName: "Features"));

var trainedModel = pipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);
```

As you can see below, since I am collecting feature names from the original trainingDataView and not what was used in the model, PFI items are incorrectly labeled.

```cs
//// Compute the permutation metrics using the properly normalized data.
var linearPredictor = trainedModel.LastTransformer;
var transformedData = trainedModel.Transform(trainingDataView);
var permutationMetrics = mlContext.BinaryClassification.PermutationFeatureImportance(
                linearPredictor, transformedData, labelColumnName: "mHiProfitOneHot", permutationCount: 3);

// Now let's look at which features are most important to the model overall.
// Get the feature indices sorted by their impact on AUC.
var sortedIndices = permutationMetrics.Select((MetricStatistics, index) => new { index, metrics.AreaUnderRocCurve })
                .OrderByDescending(feature => Math.Abs(feature.AreaUnderRocCurve))
                .Select(feature => feature.index);

// Get the feature names from the training set
var featureNames =
    trainingDataView.Schema.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(column => column.Name) // Get the column names
    .Where(name => name != "mHiProfitOneHot") // Drop the Label
    .ToArray();


Console.WriteLine("Feature\tModel Weight\tChange in AUC\t95% Confidence in the Mean Change in AUC");
var auc = permutationMetrics.Select(x => x.AreaUnderRocCurve).ToArray();
foreach (int i in sortedIndices)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1:0.00}\t{2:G4}\t{3:G4}",
         featureNames[i],
         linearPredictor.Model.SubModel.TrainedTreeEnsemble.TreeWeights[i],
         auc[i].Mean,
         1.96 * auc[i].StandardError);
}
```

Is it possible to extract the subset of feature names directly from the model?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can search your model (assuming that it's a TransformerChain, as it seems to be in your case) looking for a ColumnConcatenatingTransformer and getting the input column names.

```cs
string[] columnNames = (model
                    .FirstOrDefault(t => t is ColumnConcatenatingTransformer) as ColumnConcatenatingTransformer)
                    ?.Columns
                    ?.FirstOrDefault(c => c.outputColumnName == "Features")
                    .inputColumnNames;
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", columnNames));
```